# Number of hands containing two different pairs

Tags: probability, combinatorics

We simultaneously extract $5$ cards from a game set of $32$ cards ($8$ Hearts, $8$ Diamonds, $8$ Spades, $8$ Clubs). This set of $5$ cards is called a "hand". I want to know how to count the hands of $5$ cards containing two different pairs (for example 7788K, QQKK9).

Comment: For clarity, you should indicate that this $32$-card deck is a subset of the standard $52$-card poker deck, with (presumably) $2$ through $6$ excluded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have $8$ ranks in each of $4$ suits. For two pairs, you need to choose $2$ ranks for the values of those pairs. There are $\binom82=28$ ways to do this. Then, for each pair, you need to choose the suits. There are $\binom42=6$ ways to do this for each pair. Finally, there are $6$ remaining ranks to choose for the unpaired card, and $4$ options for the suit gives $6\times4=24$ options for the fifth card. The total is:
$$\binom82\times\binom42\times\binom42\times24=24192$$

Comment: To choose the unpaired card, we only have to choose a different value, so 32-8=24. Why do you consider only 16 ways to do it.

Comment: @DavidLingard Thanks for pointing that out. I guess I just had 16 on my brain.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig David is correct, as there are $6$ ranks available for the fifth card, and $4$ suits gives $6\times4=24$

Comment: I am not sure why I am confusing ranks and suits today.  However, you are correct.

Comment: thanks for the answer!!